# Using jq unique_by with arrays

Tags: arrays, json, unique, jq

I am running jq 1.6. After hours of frustration trying different ways of using unique_by I decided I don't understand what it is doing and I haven't found an example similar to my use case

I pipe curl output into a jq and do some processing. I then pipe the output to another jq to remove duplicates in "sub"arrays with:

jq '. |= unique_by(.bound_to[].where_to)'

the input being pipped into the above command looks like the below. I only want 1 entry in each bound_to array. As you can see record 2 and 3 have duplicates, yet unique_by doesn't remove them. Am I referencing it correctly or should I use a different filter combination?

I don't get any errors, but I also still have all the bound_to entries in the output.

thank you

~~ INPUT TO JQ ~~

```
[{
  "location": "S24C2B1F1",
  "bound_to": [
    {
      "access_ids": [],
      "system_ssn": "",
      "where_to": 11
    }
  ],
  "description": null,
  "ipv4": "192.168.11.1",
  "id": "50011"
},
{
  "location": "S24C2B1F2",
  "bound_to": [
    {
      "access_ids": [],
      "system_ssn": "",
      "where_to": 3
    },
    {
      "access_ids": [],
      "system_ssn": "",
      "where_to": 3
    },
    {
      "access_ids": [],
      "system_ssn": "",
      "where_to": 3
    }
  ],
  "description": null,
  "ipv4": "10.10.3.254",
  "id": "60003"
},
{
  "location": "S48C1B2F1",
  "bound_to": [
    {
      "access_ids": [],
      "system_ssn": "",
      "where_to": 10
    },
    {
      "access_ids": [],
      "system_ssn": "",
      "where_to": 10
    }
  ],
  "description": null,
  "ipv4": "192.168.10.1",
  "id": "50010"
}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

The task as I understand it can easily (and perhaps most easily) be accomplished using `unique`:

```
map( .bound_to |= unique )
```

Comment: thank you. that did accomplish what I was trying to accomplish with unique_by.

issue resolved.